# xml http request is not working in opera mini

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, opera-mini

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    alert(this.status) // this alert showing 0
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log("data==", this.responseText)
        //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "url", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({"name":"myname" }));
```

above is my code which is working fine in desktop opera and all other browsers but in opera mini it is not working, status is 0, can someone help me out please.

Comment: status 0 menas: request not initialized.Please post the response you are getting.

Comment: request is not hitting server, below is the error message we are getting in error handler method.

ECMAscript errors
{"bubbles":false,"cancelBubble":false,"cancelable":false,"currentTarget":{"readyState":4,"response":"","responseText":"","responseType":"","responseXML":{"async":true,"attributes":null,"baseURI":null,"characterSet":"utf-8","contentType":"application/xml","cookie":"","defaultView":null,"dir":"","doctype":null,"documentElement":null,"documentURI":null,"firs{"MODE_SYNCHRONOUS":1,"MODE_ASYNCHRONOUS":2},
enter==== 0 state== 4

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end @VamshiKrishnaLakkars

Comment: Opera mini doesn't support XMLHttpRequest. See: https://caniuse.com/?search=xmlhttprequest.